# Romance Fantasy webcomic about a girl raised by nuns who marries a duke

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, webcomics

The main character (MC) is a girl raised in a church by some nuns. I can't remember her name. She overhears the priest making a deal with a noble to sell her off as a "gift" for the local Duke that everybody has heard a lot of rumors about, like saying he's impotent/can't use his legs, etc. She asks her childhood friend to marry her, so the priest won't be able to sell her off after all.

Surprise, surprise, her childhood friend IS the Duke and he's been hiding his identity the whole time because of the rumors and he's been hopelessly in love with her since they were kids. He has abilities relating to the underworld - he can summon the soul of someone dead to interrogate them and his servants are all undead souls or demons called Reapers.

It turns out the main character is from the noble family blessed by some goddess? Except the family has been obsessed with keeping the bloodline pure; you know how that goes. So the goddess actually abandoned the rest of the family and once the MC awakens her powers, the goddess gets a material form and latches on like some overprotective helicopter mom? Meanwhile, the family found out she existed and still has the goddess' blessing, so the guy who wants to be emperor next, her cousin or something, wants to make her his wife to solidify his political standing or something.

It is driving me crazy that I pretty clearly remember the plot and lore but can't remember a single character name or the title.
I only have the following apps for webcomics: Webtoon, Pocket Comics, Manta, Tapas and Tappytoon. I know FOR SURE it wasn't Manta or Tappytoon though.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead and/or the male lead?

Comment: Any idea when you read this, i.e. about what year? Additionally, those sites mostly publish Korean webtoons; is there any chance this was originally in a different language (i.e. originally English or Chinese)?

Comment: The FL had light colored hair but idr exactly what color it was. Ml has black hair. And my goldfish brain read it within like the last 3 months.... im just dumb and forgot the important bits to find it again!! Unfortunately I do not know if it was originally published in a different language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[From BFF to Obsessive Hubby](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/from-bff-to-obsessive-hubby)*. It is licensed by Tapas.

> Isabelle has always dreamed of meeting her true love and living happily ever after. Unfortunately, she discovers that **she was just sold to the monstrous Duke Cardiego**, who's infamous for killing his bride candidates. Her only way out is to quickly **marry someone else, and as it turns out, her BFF Lix is the perfect choice**! Although she tells him she will just stay a friend, Lix begins to show her that he doesn't feel the same way. Will their friendship be able to last through this matrimony?

The main character lives in a temple, raised by nuns after her parents abandoned her as a baby. The story opens with her overhearing that the priest was going to sell her off to the infamous duke. As mentioned in the question, there are rumors that he has a dysfunctional lower body.

[image: Sold by priest]   [image: Rumors about the duke]

The main character has silver hair, this is mentioned early on as being "favored" by the goddess. I haven't read enough to explicitly confirm the divine connection; it's just considered beautiful/"lucky" for her to have that color hair.

The "BFF" she plans to marry to escape the Duke is indeed the Duke. It's not mentioned in the synopsis but is very obvious even in the 2nd chapter. They met as children while he ran away from a festival due to an assassination attempt.